# GTM server side container setup not possible

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a problem setting up server-side container using the Google Cloud Platform. I get the message that my Google Cloud contingent would be used up (with 5 projects sitting there so far). I didn't limit it and I don't see how to unlimit it (Please take my money Google!). I looked around for an hour for a solution but can't find any. Anyone here has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

GTM server side container setup not possible
https://measuremindsgroup.com/set-up-gtm-server-side